# Running Logistic Regression in R

Tags: r, regression, spss

I'm running logistic regression in R for the first time. Usually I do this in SPSS but my output in R is different.

In SPSS I'd run it like this:

```
LOGISTIC REGRESSION VARIABLES benefits
/METHOD=ENTER hhinc_band
/CONTRAST (hhinc_band)=INDICATOR
/PRINT=SUMMARY CI(95)
/CRITERIA=PIN(0.05) POUT(0.10) ITERATE(20) CUT(0.5).
```

In R, I'm doing this:

```
logistic <- glm(benefits ~ hhinc_band, 
data=data2017)
```

In order to achieve the same output do I need to run anything extra in R?

Grateful for any guidance.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I think the default option in glm is gaussian. You can run a logistic model by specifying the family:

```
 glm(benefits ~ hhinc_band, data=data2017, family = "binomial")
```

See here for more info  https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/